# Elasticsearch delete api only deletes the record from one shard. The record still can be searched unless I manually delete & rebuild the whole index

Tags: elasticsearch

Elasticsearch delete api only deletes the record from one shard.
The record still can be searched unless I manually delete & rebuild the whole index.

Following is the response of Delete API:

```
{"found":false,"_index":"companyindex","_type":"companydata","_id":"932","_version":1,"_shards":{"total":2,"successful":1,"failed":0}}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in document id. Actually, we were outputting user_id as document_id. So the company_id was never going to be found. Hence we got {"found : false} in the cURL response.

Sorry to say, question text also needs little bit modification. Record was never deleted from 1 shard (after correcting myself, record exists on only node irrespective of how many shards it has)